# Animation difference between UIView and UIButton

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uibutton

In my custom table view cell, I have 4 buttons with an animation (shown below). The problem is when I'm using an `UIButton`, the animation doesn't animate as I wanted. But when I use an `UIView`, it works exactly as how I want it.

The code is exactly the same with only the difference of using a different type of `UIView`.

This animation is using an **`UIButton`**:

[image: Animation with a button]

This animation is using an **`UIView`**

[image: Animation with a UIView]

To make things a bit more clear, the only thing I've replaced in the code is:

```
// Test with Buttons
let button1 = Button()  // Subclass of UIButton
let button2 = Button()    

// Test with UIViews
let button1 = UIView()
let button2 = UIView()
```

---

**Question:**
Can someone tell me why a `UIButton` behaves differently compared to a normal `UIView`?

---

Initially I thought by not posting the code, I could make the question easier to read as both tests are using exactly the same code (except for the "element" (element being `UIView` or `UIButton`), and thought perhaps the problem lies in the difference between the "elements". I realize now that this was my mistake.

**My code:**

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    private var base: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    private var open: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    var buttons: [UIView] = []

    private var active = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let button1 = CustomButton(frame: CGRectZero, color: UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor)
        let button2 = CustomButton(frame: CGRectZero, color: UIColor.redColor().CGColor)

    //  let button1 = UIView(); button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    //  let button2 = UIView(); button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let views = ["button1": button1, "button2": button2]

        buttons = [button1, button2]

        buttons.enumerate().forEach {
            $0.element.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0.element)

            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[button\($0.index + 1)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))

            base += [NSLayoutConstraint(item: $0.element, attribute: .Width , relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: buttons.first!, attribute: .Width , multiplier: 1, constant: 0)]
        }

        open += [NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttons.last!, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: buttons.first!, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.33, constant: 0)]           
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[button1]-0.5-[button2]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        addConstraints(base)

        backgroundColor = .blackColor()
        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func changeState() {
        removeConstraints(active ? open : base); addConstraints(active ? base : open)

        active = !active

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { self.layoutIfNeeded() })
    }
}
```

**Solution:**
After posting the code and accidentally changing the background color of the buttons, I noticed that it was behaving accordingly. This made me realize I was using a `CAShapeLayer` in the buttons which is causing the behaviour seen in the first animation. Now I know what to fix. If this post should be closed or deleted, please tell me so. Then I will delete the answer. And thanks for those who tried to help!

Comment: Do you mind telling me why the down vote? I don't mind adding the code for animating it, but seeing as it works for an `UIView` I think it would just make the post unnecessarily longer.

Comment: Could you please add the animation code? That's probably the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

Without you providing more details the only thing I can do is guessing that the behaviour you are witnessing comes down to buttons being less "elastic" than views, in that they have a "natural" size determined by their content (title and/or image) and auto layout really likes enforcing that natural size (as you can see from IB's warnings).

If you need more help, you should provide more details. Are you actually using auto layout? What constraints? What are you animating? etc.